# Whilst using 3 if statements in a row, even if the third one is true it does nothing

Tags: python, if-statement

I started learning programming and my first language is Python.

I got an exercise where I need to return a certain string based on an input number.
If multiple conditions are true, it has to concatenate strings and print the answer in console.

Here is the code:

```
number = int(input("enter your number here: "))

def plingplangplong(number):
    strPling = "pling"
    strPlong = "plong"
    strPlang = "plang"
    strAnswer = ""

    if number % 3 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPling
    if number % 5 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlong
    if number % 7 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlang
    elif strAnswer:
        print(strAnswer)
    else:
        print(number)


plingplangplong(number)
```

If I enter a number divisible by `7` it doesn't provide any output on console. Why?

If I enter `3` or `5` it works. `30` and `60` work returning 'plingplong' as expected.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Read about [if-elif](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/ifstatements.html#multiple-tests-and-if-elif-statements) statements. the 'elif' and `else` statements in your code refers to the line `if number % 7 == 0` which means that if the number divides with 7 you will only build the string, but won't print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is printing stuff only if `number` is *not* divisible by 7, because all the `print`s are in the `elif/else` blocks:

```
if number % 7 == 0:
    strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlang
elif strAnswer:
    # we get here only when the first `if` condition is NOT true
    print(strAnswer)
else:
    # we get here only when the first `if` condition and the `elif` condition are NOT true
    print(number)
```

You should change it like this:

```
if number % 7 == 0:
    strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlang

if strAnswer:
    print(strAnswer)
else:
    print(number)
```

Comment: thank you! i don't know why used an elif statement for the 4th one.  dumb oversight of me. makes total sense! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
number = int(input("enter your number here: "))
def plingplangplong(number):

    strPling = "pling"
    strPlong = "plong"
    strPlang = "plang"
    strAnswer = ""

    if number % 3 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPling
    if number % 5 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlong
    if number % 7 == 0:
        strAnswer = strAnswer + strPlang

    if strAnswer:
        print(strAnswer)
    else:
        print(number)


plingplangplong(number)
```